# Heroku postgresql max number of connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

base on this one https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans
heroku specifies the max number of connection in the database.

my question is, does the max number of connection equal to the number of logged in users?

like If I have max limit of 60, does it mean I can have max 60 logged in users?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it means your app should have at most 60 db connections open in it's connection pool. That just means your app can only send 60 simultaneous requests to the db.

It has nothing to do with logged in users, but if your 61 logged in users simultaneously send requests to your app, one of them is going to wait a bit till a connection is free in the connection pool.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html